# Marginal predictions from a conditional survival model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, survival, treatment-effect, conditional, marginal-model

I’m looking at making predictions of baseline and treated survival from a parametric survival curve that are unbiased. I have a matched sample to try to control for observed confounding and wanted to use doubly robust estimates in my treatment effect model by controlling for covariates.

I was wondering, if it was valid to estimate, say, a exponential survival curve, with a treatment variable and some control variables, then take the treatment effect parameter and intercept from this model into a pexp function in R and make predictions with just these parameters and plot a marginal exponential survival curve, and leave out the other predictors? I’m not sure if this breaks any statistical rules.

Edit

I'm trying to do something like the below. I have estimated the conditional treatment effect and estimated parameters for treatment and covariates. Now, I just want to plot a survival curves for the baseline and treatment parameters with these parameters only to get the marginal distribution. The idea was to remove any bias caused by the covariates through the GLM then predict what survival looks like for baseline and treatment only I was wondering if this procedure is valid.

```
t<-seq(0,max(pbc$time),50)
boot_fit_exp <- flexsurvreg((Surv(time, status) ~ trt+age+sex), data = pbc, dist = "exp")
coef_boot_fit_exp <- coef(boot_fit_exp)
hazard <- exp(coef_boot_fit_exp[1] + coef_boot_fit_exp[2])
# Calculate survival probability
surv_prob_baseline <- 1-pexp(t,boot_fit_exp$res[1])

surv_prob_trt <- 1-pexp(t,as.vector(hazard))
```

Any help on this would be really appreciated, thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to say more about how you intend to use the "marginal exponential survival curve." In general this poses problems, as the mean survival of a population over time can be far from the survival of an individual with mean covariate values, with the latter seeming to be pretty much what you propose. There might be some uses for which your curve would be acceptable, but your use case isn't clear from the question as posed. More details about the nature of the data behind the model would help, too.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for pointing this out! I've added some detail, let me know if this is not what you were getting at.

Comment: [Austin et al. (2020)](https://doi.org/10.1177/0962280218817926) describe how to get doubly-robust marginal survival effects after matching. I don't know if they developed a standard error for it, though. [Denz et al. (2022)](http://arxiv.org/abs/2203.10002) review several methods for covariate-adjusted marginal hazard ratios.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your approach. One is a simple oversight in the way that you set up your example. The second is fundamental, in that your approach doesn't provide a true marginal estimate over the population of interest.

First, the parametric survival estimate needs to include all predictor variables that contribute to the linear predictor. The distribution of survival times $T$ in an exponential model conditional on a vector $X$ of covariate values can be written as:

$$\log T \sim X'\beta +W $$

where $\beta$ is the corresponding vector of coefficients and $W$ has a standard minimum extreme value distribution. In your construction of the baseline hazard you omitted entries for `age` or `sex`, effectively setting `age` to 0 and `sex` to the reference level of `m`. That's certainly not a "marginal" survival estimate. If you plot your "baseline" survival against the corresponding raw data, you will see that your "baseline" survival estimates are much too high, probably because of effectively setting `age=0`.

Second, you might think that you can get around that problem by specifying values for `age` and `sex`. But which to choose? The `pbc` data set illustrates the problem nicely:

```
with(pbc,coef(lm(age~sex)))
# (Intercept)        sexf 
#   55.710721   -5.553778
```

The average age for females is over 5 years less than that for males. What single combination of `age` and `sex` could possibly be used to get anything like a marginal survival estimate this way? Would you use the average `sex` representation of 0.89 of a female in the `pbc` data set? Furthermore, the survival of an "average" individual, even if you could define such an individual, can be far from the true marginal survival, an average of survival versus time over the population of interest.

For example, based on your model you can determine $S_i(t)$ for an appropriate set of $N$ individuals $i$ representing the population, and calculate the Ederer estimate:

$$S_e(t)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N S_i(t) .$$

There's a `survexp()` function in the R `survival` package to do that, or to provide other estimates of cohort survival. Each of those has potential problems, however, discussed in detail in Chapter 10 of [Therneau and Grambsch](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387987842). In particular, after decades of effort, the authors of the package still don't have a reliable way to calculate standard errors for these estimates. However you end up trying to get marginal survival estimates, be very careful in how you interpret them.

Finally, consider whether marginal estimates are needed at all. As this [post by Frank Harrell](https://www.fharrell.com/post/marg/) documents, they are highly problematic in binomial or survival regression models and depend on the composition of the population used to build the model. Such marginal estimates might not carry over well to a different population. Furthermore, a treatment decision in clinical practice should always be conditional upon a particular patient's situation, not some estimated population-average treatment effect. Illustrating survival curves conditional upon particular typical covariate values and treatment choices is a more useful way to document a model's results, unless a treatment is being applied to an entire population (as in the water-fluoridation example noted in that post).